# How to get different ids value of radio button

Tags: c#, jquery, model-view-controller, .net-core

how to get radio button checked value for different multiple ids to constorller on form submit

```
@Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.IsCorrectAnswerOption1, "IsCorrectAnswerOption1")<lable>A</lable>
@Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.IsCorrectAnswerOption2, "IsCorrectAnswerOption2")<lable>B</lable>
@Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.IsCorrectAnswerOption3, "IsCorrectAnswerOption3")<lable>C</lable>
@Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.IsCorrectAnswerOption4, "IsCorrectAnswerOption4")<lable>D</lable>
```

(or)

```
<input type="radio" name="IsCorrectAnswerOption1" id="IsCorrectAnswerOption1" /> A
<input type="radio" name="IsCorrectAnswerOption2" id="IsCorrectAnswerOption2" /> B
<input type="radio" name="IsCorrectAnswerOption3" id="IsCorrectAnswerOption3" /> C
<input type="radio" name="IsCorrectAnswerOption4" id="IsCorrectAnswerOption4" /> D
```

This is my action method in contorller:

```
public ActionResult Submit(QuestionBank questionBank)
        {
            int status;
            string constr = ConfigurationExtensions.GetConnectionString(Configuration, "conStr");
            using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(constr))
            {
                using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("spSaveQuestionandAnswers"))
                {
                    connection.Open();

                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SectionID", questionBank.SectionId);
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DifficultyLevelID", questionBank.DifficultyLevelID);
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@QBQuestion", questionBank.QBQuestion);
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Option1", questionBank.Option1);
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Option2", questionBank.Option2);
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Option3", questionBank.Option3);
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Option4", questionBank.Option4);
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@QBWeightage", questionBank.QBWeightage);
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IsCorrectAnswerOption1", questionBank.IsCorrectAnswerOption1);
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IsCorrectAnswerOption2", questionBank.IsCorrectAnswerOption2);
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IsCorrectAnswerOption3", questionBank.IsCorrectAnswerOption3);
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IsCorrectAnswerOption4", questionBank.IsCorrectAnswerOption4);
                    command.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    command.Connection = connection;
                    //SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
                    int numberOfRecords = command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    ViewBag.Response = numberOfRecords;
                    Response.Headers["test"] = numberOfRecords.ToString();

                    //status = command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                   // reader.Close();
                    connection.Close();


                }
            }
```

This is my action method
                return RedirectToAction("QuestionBank");
            }

Comment: What you tried?

Comment: in ajax call i am sending complete  data: $('#QuestionBankForm').serialize(), but in controller i am unable to get the value of checked one

Comment: Show your controller's action method.

Comment: i have updated controller code in question

Comment: So did you get posted data in `QuestionBank` in method paramter?

Comment: yes but not the checked value of radio button it is eveytime giving false but not true and i have four different ids for four radio buttons

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this in order to send your selected radio boxes values to your `Controller` method:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Submit", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { @id = "myFormId", @class = "form-horizontal", role = "form", enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()
{
 <input type="radio" name="childChkbox" value="IsCorrectAnswerOption1" id="checkAll" /> A
 <input type="radio" name="childChkbox" value="IsCorrectAnswerOption2" id="checkAll" /> B
 <input type="radio" name="childChkbox" value="IsCorrectAnswerOption3" id="checkAll" /> C
 <input type="radio" name="childChkbox" value="IsCorrectAnswerOption4" id="checkAll" /> D

<input id="submitform" type="submit" value="Submit Information" class="btn btn-primary btn-md" />
}
```

And your `Controller` method will look like:

```
//Receive your Radiobox values here for selected radioboxes
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Submit(QuestionBank questionBank, string[] childChkbox)
{
  //Here you get selected ID's list as required
  List<int> myList=childChkbox.Select(int.Parse).ToList();   
}
```

Comment: getting error System.FormatException: 'Input string was not in a correct format.' for this  List<int> myList=childChkbox.Select(int.Parse).ToList();

Comment: @Arun Try to debug and change the list type according to what value you are sending. I was assuming a list of ints. It might be string in your case.

Answer (score 0):

It seems your model properties from `IsCorrectAnswerOption1` to `IsCorrectAnswerOption4` are booleans

So if you try to initialize boolean values `true` or `false` then it might be you will get boolean values in your action method

```
@Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.IsCorrectAnswerOption1, true)<lable>A</lable>
@Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.IsCorrectAnswerOption2, false)<lable>B</lable>
@Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.IsCorrectAnswerOption3, false)<lable>C</lable>
@Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.IsCorrectAnswerOption4, false)<lable>D</lable>
```